# AVPlayerLayer not displaying in correct orientation

Tags: ios, avplayer, avcapturesession, avplayerlayer

I'm currently developing an App which records a video and then shows you the video to check if the video was good enough. However when displaying the recorded video, it shows it in the wrong orientation..

So basically I'm recording it in LandscapeRight modus. But when displaying it displays it in portrait mode, and also apparently records it in display mode as well. Even when I set it AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight.

Here is the code I'm using to setup the recording:

```
func setupAVCapture(){
        session =  AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
        // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
        for device in devices {
            // Make sure this particular device supports video
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                    if captureDevice != nil {
                        beginSession()
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func beginSession(){
        var err : NSError? = nil
        var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput?
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            deviceInput = nil
        };
        if err != nil {
            print("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
            self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
        }


        self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        self.videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
        self.videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
        self.videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
        if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
            session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
        }
        self.videoDataOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).enabled = true

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.previewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight


        let rootLayer :CALayer = CameraPreview.layer
        rootLayer.masksToBounds=true
        rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        session.startRunning()

    }
```

After this the next delegate gets called and I display it in the same view, but for a playback:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        playbackAvailable = true
        SaveButton.hidden = false
        recording = false

        stopCamera()

//        let library = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()
//        library.performChanges({ PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(outputFileURL)! }, completionHandler: {success, error in debugPrint("Finished saving asset. %@", (success ? "Success." : error!)) })

        // Play Video
        player = AVPlayer(URL: outputFileURL)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.masksToBounds = true
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        CameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
```

Now the playback displays it in the wrong orientation, anyone knows how to fix this? I've also got the orientation of the viewcontroller to LandscapeRight.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
// Neccesary to record in the correct orientation
        // ** MUST BE IMPLEMENTED AFTER SETING UP THE MOVIEFILE **
        var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection? = nil
        if let connections = videoFileOutput.connections{
            for x in connections {
                if let connection = x as? AVCaptureConnection{
                    for port in connection.inputPorts{
                        if(port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo){
                            videoConnection = connection
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(videoConnection != nil){
            if let vidConnect: AVCaptureConnection = videoConnection!{
                if(vidConnect.supportsVideoOrientation){
                    vidConnect.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.rawValue)!
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically you need to set the AVCaptureVideoOrientation of the connection to the correct orientation before you start recording. Or else it might record in the wrong orientation.

Comment: Can you share how this was implmented?